# Mongo go driver's DocumentCount does not support $nearSphere

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am working on geo location query where I want to get total number of collections that satisfy geo location query. Mongo go library provides Document Count method with doesn't support filter based on geo location.

The error I am getting is:
(BadValue) $geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context

```
filter := bson.D{
    {
        Key: "address.location",
        Value: bson.D{
            {
                Key: "$nearSphere",
                Value: bson.D{
                    {
                        Key: "$geometry",
                        Value: bson.D{
                            {
                                Key:   "type",
                                Value: "Point",
                            },
                            {
                                Key:   "coordinates",
                                Value: bson.A{query.Longitude, query.Latitude},
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        Key:   "$maxDistance",
                        Value: maxDistance,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
collection := db.Database("catalog").Collection("restaurant")
totalCount, findError := collection.CountDocuments(ctx, filter)
```

Comment: What is the query?

Comment: The error is helpful but you need to include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: I have added sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (BadValue) $geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context

You're getting this message due to the restricted use of [db.collection.countDocuments()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/).

The method `countDocuments()` essentially wraps aggregation pipeline `$match` and `$group`. See [The Mechanics of countDocuments()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#mechanics) for more information. There are a number of query operators that are restricted : [Query Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#query-restrictions), one of them being [$nearSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#op._S_nearSphere) operator.

An alternative is to use [$geoWithin] and [$centerSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#op._S_centerSphere):

```
filter := bson.D{ 
  { Key: "address.location", 
    Value: bson.D{ 
        { Key: "$geoWithin", 
            Value: bson.D{ 
                { Key: "$centerSphere", 
                  Value: bson.A{ 
                            bson.A{ query.Longitude, query.Latitude } , 
                            maxDistance}, 
                }, 
            },
        },
    },
  }}
```

Note that the `maxDistance` in spherical geometry has to be in a radius. You need to convert the distance, for example `10/6378.1` for 10 kilometres please see [Calculate Distance using Spherical Geometry](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) for more information.

Also worth mentioning that although [$centerSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/) works *without* having a geospatial index, geospatial indexes support much faster queries than the unindexed equivalents.